Arbitrary irreducible polynomials over a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$
Let $F$ be a degree $q$ (prime) extension over $\mathbb{Q}$ which is not normal. Show that for each $n$, there exists irreducible polynomials of degree $n$ over $F$. I have been trying this question for too long. Any hint is appreciated.
Edit 1: Ok. I just figured out an analogous result is true in case of finite fields. Let $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ be a finite field. Consider the polynomial $x^{p^{n}} - x$, which is separable over $\mathbb{F}_{p}$. Its not hard to show that the splitting field of this polynomial is $\mathbb{F}_{p^{n}}$. Now by primitive element theorem there exists $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}_{p^{n}}$ such that $\mathbb{F}_{p}(\alpha) = \mathbb{F}_{p^{n}}$. Hence $[\mathbb{F}_{p^{n}} : \mathbb{F}_{p}] = [\mathbb{F}_{p}(\alpha) : \mathbb{F}_{p}] = n$. Hence the degree of the minimal polynomial, which is in particular irreducible, of $\alpha$ is $n$.
Does the same idea work here?
Edit 2: I was trying to consider a suitable extension $F(\zeta_{p})$ where $\zeta_{p}$ is the primitive root of unity of order $p$ and trying to get $[F(\zeta_{p}) : F] = n$. But it is taking me nowhere

For the case $\gcd(n,q)=1$, you can just choose your polynomial to be $x^n-2$. I couldn't think of any way to deal with the case $q \mid n$, but the discussion here may help: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/36617/given-an-integer-n-and-a-finite-extension-k-of-q-find-a-polynomial-of-degree-n

If $F$ is any finite extension of the rationals, then for all $n$ there are polynomials of degree $n$ irreducible over $F$.

@GerryMyerson Hi, I read your solution for the statement about the existence of irreducible of degree $n$ in a field extension, but I am not sure why there exists $p \equiv 1 \pmod n$ such that $K \cap \mathbb{Q}({e^{2i\pi/p}}) =\mathbb{Q}$. Could you perhaps elaborate or help me with some hints why such prime exists?

@Tri, there are infinitely many $p\equiv1\bmod n$ by a theorem of Dirichlet. $K$ being a finite extension of the rationals can only contain finitely many of the numbers $e^{2\pi i/p}$.

@GerryMyerson Ah I see. It is clear now, thank you so much.

@GerryMyerson Why is $K(e ^{\frac{2\pi i}{p}})$ a cyclic extension of $K$ of degree a multiple of $n$?

Have you done any Galois Theory, Dwaipayan? $\zeta=e^{2\pi i/p}$ is of degree $p-1$, which is a multiple of $n$. The automorphisms take $\zeta$ to $\zeta^k$ for $k=1,2,\dotsc,p-1$; the group of automorphisms is isomorphic to the multiplicative group of the integers modulo $p$, which is the cyclic group of order $p-1$.

Also posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/482932/irreducible-polynomials-of-arbitrary-degree-over-number-fields-of-prime-degree-b – what kind of game are you playing, Dwaipayan?

@GerryMyerson I am taking a Galois Theory course and yes it is cyclic group of order $p - 1$, I forgot the crucial assumption we are choosing $p$, to be equivalent to modulo $n$. Thanks Gerry.

@GerryMyerson  Ripan and I are brothers. We were trying the problem together. Since he does not have any account on stack exchange, I insisted him to post the same question with what we have tried in math overflow. I will tell him to close the question. I am sorry on both of our behalf.

@GerryMyerson Btw I am totally okay with the argument you just gave if we would have replaced $K$ by $\mathbb{Q}$, i.e., $\mathbb{Q} (\zeta_{p})$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ will be of degree a multiple of $n$ . But I am not completely sure how the same argument works for $K$ which is a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. I think we want to use the fact that $p$ was chosen such that $K \cap \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{p}) = \mathbb{Q}$. But I am not sure how. I will be thankful if you could please explain that. Thanks.

Sorry, I've had enough of you and your brother and your abuse of these sites. Go away. Both of you, just go away.

@GerryMyerson We are just trying to learn math. In future we would be mindful of maintaining the decorum of these sites. Sorry

You can use Eisenstein’s criterion (or the rational root test) to produce a collection of irreducible degree $n$ polynomials over $\mathbb{Q}$, e.g. $\{x^n-p,x^n-q,rx^n-p\}$ for primes $p,r$. Then, you can show the extensions obtained by adjoining a root from distinct polynomials from this collection to $\mathbb{Q}$ yield field extensions with trivial intersection. Then you can show at least one of these fields has trivial intersection with $F$, at which point you’re basically done.

How to show atleast one of these fields has a trivial intersection with F?

This is where you want to use that $[F:\mathbb{Q}]$ is prime; if two of those fields have non trivial intersection with $F$, then they must be equal.

Sorry I did not get it.

I was trying to consider a suitable extension $F(\zeta_{p})$ where $\zeta_{p}$ is the primitive root of unity of order $p$ and trying to get $[F(\zeta_{p}) : F] = n$. But it is taking me nowhere

Since the degree of $F$ is prime, the only way another field $K$ can have nontrivial intersection with $F$ is if $K=F$; since those three fields suggested mutually have trivial intersection, only one of them can have nontrivial intersection with $F$, or else they would be equal.
